# Java Princeton import error

Tags: java, graphical-programming, stddraw

I am revisiting a project that I done at university a few years ago that involved using the Princeton StdDraw Class.

When I try to execute it now in eclipse it is giving me an error that "the import princeton cannot be resolved". I have downloaded the stdlib.jar file again and added it to the build path of the project but I still have the same error. I have also tried to change the import name to edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw but still no joy.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
import princeton.StdDraw;

StdDraw.setCanvasSize(1355, 660);
```

Comment: What is inside the JAR? Do you see the package and class you are trying to import defined there and a .class? Have you refreshed the project after adding to build path?

Comment: Hi, I have refreshed the project yes. I'm not sure how to look inside a jar file. Sorry, my Java knowledge is very rusty.. it's been a few years since I looked at it

Comment: I can see the StdDraw.class inside the JAR in the package explorer in eclipse. It is in a default package

Comment: Try this since you are using Eclipse. Remove your imports manually, that is, remove all imports related to Princeton. But don't remove your StdDraw.setCanvasSize(1355, 660); call. Then press CTRL+SHIFT+O which is auto-import. It should import the correct class if it can find it. If it can't find it, then there is something wrong in your build path. My guess is that you are just providing the wrong package path to this class. See if that works and let me know.

Comment: I tried that and it hasn't imported anything. Strange.This package path worked a few years back. How would I find out the correct package path?

Comment: Open the JAR with WinRAR or some other ZIP utility and note the folder structure that leads to your .class. For example, you may see some folder like `princeton`, inside it folder `stuff`, and inside that you have your `StdDraw.class`, so then your full import would have to be `princeton.stuff.StdDraw`. But my guess is that you have not set the build path correctly. Right click your project in the project explorer and go to Properties, then on the left click Java build path and go to Libraries tab. See what's there

Comment: I've solved it. I added the wrong JAR file somehow. I added stdlib-package.jar now from princeton instead of stdlib.jar and it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem glad you got it working